# Binding objects to functions in Javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
let user = {
  firstName: "John",
  sayHi() {
    alert(`Hello, ${this.firstName}!`);
  }
};

let sayHi = user.sayHi.bind(user); 

sayHi(); // Hello, John!

setTimeout(sayHi, 1000); // Hello, John!

// even if the value of user changes within 1 second
// sayHi uses the pre-bound value which is reference to the old user object
user = {
  sayHi() { alert("Another user in setTimeout!"); }
};
```

Why this weird behaviour ? If i change the value of method shouldn't it just use the changed value .
How does it obtain `user` in lexical environment ?

Comment: `.bind()` creates a new function, so the `sayHi` variable isn't "linked" in to `user`

Comment: Well, it kind of is linked @NickParsons. They just aren't changing the `user` object, they are reassigning a new object to the variable. If instead, they did  this at the end, it *would* change the output `user.firstName = "Nick"`

Comment: @Mark yes, good point. I guess what I really meant is that the `sayHi` variable now refers to a new function object in memory and not to the one created in `user`. But yes, I agree that it is still linked in a sense that `user` is now bounded as the `this` value for that new function that has been created. So even if they were to do `user.sayHi = () => alert("Another user in setTimeout!");` after doing `let sayHi = ...`, it still wouldn't show the new output, but would change if they change `.firstName` like you mentioned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're conflating variables and objects.

After this...

```
let user = {
  firstName: "John",
  sayHi() {
    alert(`Hello, ${this.firstName}!`);
  }
};
```

You have a variable called `user`, containing an object. But the object is not the variable, and the variable is not the object. If you were to run `user = null`, the object would still exist, until garbage collected.

Next, you run

```
let sayHi = user.sayHi.bind(user);
```

Now you have another variable, containing a bound function. The function is bound to the **object** currently sitting in `user`, but it has nothing to do with the `user` variable, except that you can still reach through that variable to manipulate the object (ie `user.firstName = "bob"`). The variable still points to the object created above.

At this point, you could run `user = null` and the function `sayHi` would still have a function, still bound to the object, which will no longer be garbage collected because there is an active reference to it. You're reassigning the variable, but not removing/replacing the object to which it points.

Later, when you run this...

```
user = {
  sayHi() { alert("Another user in setTimeout!"); }
};
```

This is *no different* than running `user = null`. The variable `sayHi` still holds the old function, still bound to the old object. The variable `user` is no longer relevant to the variable `sayHi` in any way. They contain two unrelated objects.